# Delegating responsibilities for business page on Facebook

Tags: facebook, social-media, administration

Suppose I have a Facebook page for a business or organization, and I want to delegate posting responsibilities to an employee. As far as I can tell, the only way to do this is to give that employee full admin status, which seems to allow removal of other admins and even permanent deletion of the page. How can I delegate responsibilities to an employee without opening up this sort of risk?

Answer (score 2):

Most major CMS applications have a plugin that allows for posting items to FB accounts. Assuming you also have an actual site for your business and it's running on top of some system, this might be something to look into. You'd just create a section, content type, or whatever's appropriate to your particular CMS, limit access to it, and post from there instead.

Comment: +1 as,.. this may be the same thing I'm saying but I'm not sure, either way it seems similarly effective.

Answer (score 1):

I've found one solution, but it's suboptimal - Facebook provides "mobile" posting via a randomly-assigned email address. This address can be given to anybody you trust to post, without giving them any other permissions to modify the page, and it can be changed at any time if it's compromised.

I'd still like to know if there's a better solution...

Answer (score 1):

Develop a backend for your Facebook page using the [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can give *all* users the ability to post content on your page, but those users won't be able to delete your site.

Unfortunately, there is not a way to give posting ability to only *some* users without making those users "Admin".

This has of course upset quite a few people. See this thread for more information:
http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=130416483643948&id=10381469571

Comment: I disagree about levels of damage. If a rogue employee made destructive and offensive posts, you could simply remove them and apologize to your fans. Sure it would be some damage, but you could take actions to minimize it - and most importantly, you'd have access to your fans to reach them and apologize. If a rogue employee could remove you as an admin and/or delete the page, though, they'd destroy your channel of damage control and apology.

Comment: Also, one should consider not just malicious/rogue employees, but also well-meaning employees who get infected with viruses. A nasty targeted virus could take control of business pages (adding a malicious admin and removing all other admins) and attempt to extort the original owner to regain control (possibly even threatening to post offensive content if payment is not made).

Comment: If someone *really* wants to hurt your business, I'm sure they can think of plenty of ways to do that that don't involve Facebook. I think trust is important. On another note, why don't you just open up the page to updates from all users? The more interactive your page is, the more likely you are to build a community. Maybe make a feature request to Facebook? I'm sure you aren't the only one who would not trust their staff enough to want such a feature.

Comment: You could create a special "Shared account", with a strong password, that is "Admin", then you'll be less likely to be hacked. At any rate, there is unfortunately no way I know of to do what you're trying to do. Perhaps see if Facebook has a feature request or feedback channel and ask for another level of permissions for power users.

Comment: FWIW, creating a special "shared account" is a violation of the Facebook ToS...